# MPI program fails to execute with -np >100 in Docker container with --previliged, how to fix it?

Tags: docker, mpi

When i execute a program using `mpirun -np 128 ./bin/frontend -xxx` with some falgs on a docker container that setted with unlimited recources and with --previliged... the underlying machine is 256 core, the program just failed to start and raise:

```
mpirun -np 128 ./bin/frontend 

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 1887 RUNNING AT d3c359878afb
=   EXIT CODE: 7
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Bus error (signal 7)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

when i set the -np less than 100, it will be executed inside the program, while with more than 100 processes, it just failed...

i do not know how to fix this, is this problem related to my docker conatiner? or something else... how to solve it?

plus, the same -np processes number can be successfully directly on my machine... but this program i need to run it with high processs number inside a docker container

i tried to check whether the maximum processes is caused by my docker, and i tried to rerun the docker with: `--ulimit nofile=65536:65536 --privileged` it still raise error...

Comment: did you try to run your application outside of docker? the error is a textbook crash that can for example occur if `malloc()` returns `NULL` but the app does not test that, so I suggest you debug this as if docker was not involved (e.g. get a strack trace and use a debugger(